# Обновление данных в ViewPager при перелистывании вкладок

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

Есть две вкладки (смотри картинку). На первой нажимаем кнопку плюс - пишем имя - сохраняемся. Теперь, при перелистывании на вторую вкладку ХОЧУ увидеть то, что я только-что сохранил. Но этого нет. Как решить вопрос?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Адаптер___________________________________________________________________
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import com.example.evgeny.myApp.fragments.ContentFragment;
import com.example.evgeny.myApp.fragments.SavedListsFragment;

public class TabsPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private String[] tabs;

    public TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs = new String[]{"Главная", "Сохраненные"};  //Пункты TabLayout
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];  //Получаю название выделеной вкладки
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new ContentFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SavedListsFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.length;
    }
}


Фрагмент в который вставляю сохраненные названия___________________________________________________________________
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.evgeny.myApp.DBHelper;
import com.example.evgeny.myApp.MainActivity;
import com.example.evgeny.myApp.R;

import static com.example.evgeny.myApp.DBHelper.LISTS_TABLE_NAME;

public class SavedListsFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    /*-------Переменные для поиска id-------*/
    ListView lvLists;


    /*---Переменные с пояснение---*/
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    Cursor cursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sCursorAdapter;
    static String itemName;                 //Сюда сохраняю имя пункта lvLists по которому было выполнено длительное нажатие

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_saved_lists, container, false);
        Log.v(MainActivity.TAG, "onCreateView SavedListsFragment");

        /*Поиск вьюшек по ID*/
        lvLists = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvLists);


        /*Присвоение обработчиков компонентам*/
        lvLists.setOnItemClickListener(this);       //Повесил обработчик быстрого нажатия пунктов lvLists
        lvLists.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);   //Повесил обработчик длительного нажатия пунктов lvLists


        readTableLists();   //Чтение и вывод всех списков в боковое меню


        return v;
    }

    //Чтение и вывод всех имеющихся списков
    public void readTableLists() {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());                                              //Создал экземпляр класса DBHelper для управдения БД
        database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();                                          //Получил доступ на чтение БД
        cursor = database.query(LISTS_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);      //Пробежал cursor-ом по всем столбцам и строкам таблицы LISTS_TABLE_NAME
        String[] from = new String[]{DBHelper.colNamesLists, DBHelper.colDateLists};        //массив столбцов, поля которых собираемся отображать
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvItemName, R.id.tvItemDate};                             //Массив View-компонентов для отображения этих стобцов
        sCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.item_listview, cursor, from, to, 0);   //Создал адаптер и настроил ему кастомный вид
        lvLists.setAdapter(sCursorAdapter);                                                 //Повесил адаптер на lvLists
        dbHelper.close();                                                                   //Закрыл подключение к БД
    }

}

Вывзов в Главном активити________________________________________________________
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.AppDefault);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.v(TAG, "Create MainActivity");

        /*Поиск вьюшек по ID*/
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);   //Активирую Toolbar

                ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);                                  //Нашел viewPager
        TabsPagerFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());   //Создаю экземпляр адаптера
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);                                                                  //Применяю адаптер к viewPager-у

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);                                 //Нашел tabLayout
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);                                                        //Привязал к нему viewPager (т.к. они работают в связке "вкладка - соответсвующий контент")


    }
```

Comment: Посмотри здесь, я думаю это то что ты ищешь:
[ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088076/update-fragment-from-viewpager)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите, чтоб данные в списке автоматически обновлялись, советую Вам использовать ContentProvider + CursorLoader. 
ContentProvider:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html?hl=ru
http://easyandroid.ru/postavshhiki-soderzhimogo-osnovy/
CursorLoader:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html?hl=ru
Еще можете использовать CallBack'и для оповещения о новой вставке, либо LocalBroadcastManager. Но всё-же я рекомендую смотреть в сторону ContentProvider.